# How would I create two inputs per line with Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to put the label on the left and have two inputs on the right, with 'addons'.  This is what I have so far, but it seems to be wrapping.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <fieldset>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">1. Some text</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="How much?">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="How much?">
    </div>
  </div>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the Bootstrap docs, this:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 input-group">
```

Is incorrect. You must put the `input-group` class on a separate div nested within the `col-xs-3` div instead, rather than chaining these classes on the same element like that.